# ASP.Net MVC and siteminder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, siteminder

I am new to siteminder. I need to build a ASP.Net MVC application and use siteminder for Single Sign On process. It would be great if someone can guide me the right direction. Looking for tutorial or real world sample application.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you need to do on the application side besides adding the correct settings in the web.config file to enable Siteminder.

This usually includes adding handlers  in the   section of the web.config file.

Similar to these two lines..

```
      <add name="handler-wa-32" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\CA\webagent\win32\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,bitness32" />
  <add name="CASiteMinderWebAgentHandler-fcc-32" path="*.fcc" verb="*" modules="CASiteMinderWebagentModule-32" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness32" />
```

And possilby a isapifilter

```
    <isapiFilters>
  <filter name="SiteMinder Agent" path="C:\Program Files\CA\webagent\win64\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" enabled="true" preCondition="classicMode,bitness64" />
</isapiFilters>
```

Are you handling the instance of Siteminder as well? The setup to enable siteminder is configured in IIS. and some of these entrys can be made through a GUI tool configuring siteminder in IIS.

We have a group that managers the servers here so I can't help you out as to the settings and configurations on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a lot out there, have you read this codeproject article

[How to Connect to a SiteMinder Protected Resource Using an HTTP Request](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80314/How-to-Connect-to-a-SiteMinder-Protected-Resource)