# ASP.NET MVC Siteminder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, siteminder

We have a site that is protected by siteminder. I am able to extract the user id information from the Http header in ASP.Net webforms as well as classic ASP pages. But the siteminder http header values are not present in MVC. It appears that the siteminder security is getting bypassed. Has anyone successfully implemented an MVC app with siteminder protection.

Thanks

Comment: can you please share the link of article or sample code where webform app can be integrated into siteminder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the order of the ISAPI filters is correct.  The SiteMinder should be first (before classic ASP and .NET) in IIS and I believe web.config needs to be changed as well.

http://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP3-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/idocs/index.htm?toc.htm?834391.html

[ASP.Net MVC and siteminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867667/asp-net-mvc-and-siteminder)

Comment: The siteminder ISAPI filter does appear first in IIS. Also tried modifying the web.config based on the link but that didn't help. Have you successfully configured siteminder to work with MVC application?